# JTable doesn't update, calling the setValueAt method doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm creating a sudoku game and I'm having quite some trouble with JTables ... 
I just can't get it to fire events, for some reason even when calling the setValueAt from the main class nothing happens. It does work when doing it inside the model itself though ...
As you can see I've tried a tableModelListener but that doesn't work either.

To sum up my question: why doesn't my table fire events and the setValuesAt method doesn't do anything?

The abstractModel:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class SudokuTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private int[][] data;
        private int[][] originalBoard;

        /**
         * 
         * @param board the board to be played with
         */


        public SudokuTableModel(int[][] board)
        {
            data = board;
            originalBoard = board;



        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() 
        {
            return 9;
        }


        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            // this
            return 9;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        {
            System.out.println("Is it editable?");
                if(originalBoard[row][col]<0) //if the value is -1 -> it is not one of the hints and thus can be edited
                    //it has to be checked with the original board because the user might want to change something they did
                    return true;
            return false;

        }

        /**
         * @return the value at row, col
         */
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) 
        {//if its a "sudoku" number, return it, otherwise return null
            //^thta doesn't seem to work so we'll just return the value. With the size of the grid, number that is not exactly 1 char will be displayed as 3 dots so its fine
            return (data[arg0][arg1]<0)?-1:data[arg0][arg1]; 
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param value changes to this value @
         * @param row
         * @param col
         */
        public boolean setValueAt(int value, int row, int col, int randomValue)
        {
            originalBoard[row][col]=value;
            System.out.println("Setting value");
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            return true;

        }

         public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
            }

    }
```

And the main code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;





/**
 * @Program Sudoku
 * 
 * @author Tomas Svitil
 * @date November 2013
 * @school CTU
 * @hardware MacBook Pro 17", mid 2010, i7, 8GiB RAM
 * @IDE eclipse SDK 4.3.1
 * @purpose this is the main playing board. Options such as save and load will be handled by a helper class -SudokuTable Helper
 *
 */

public class SudokuTablePreRenderer extends JFrame implements TableModelListener
{


      JTable table;
        int[][] board;



    /**
     * 
     * @param toBeUsed the board to be used
     * @param isSolution if true the 'close' button just disposes the window
     */
    public SudokuTablePreRenderer(int[][] toBeUsed,boolean isSolution) 
    {

        //lets use our sudoku model
        SudokuTableModel model = new SudokuTableModel(toBeUsed);
        //make a copy of the passed 
        board=toBeUsed;
        table = new JTable( model )
        {
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
            {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                JComponent jc = (JComponent)c;
                if(!isRowSelected(row))
                {
                    c.setBackground(toBeGray(row,column) ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    boolean top = top(row);
                    boolean left = left(column);
                    boolean bottom = bottom(row);
                    boolean right = right(column);
                    jc.setBorder(new MatteBorder(top?1:0,left?1:0,bottom?1:0,right?1:0, Color.BLACK));
                }
                return c;
            }
            //each returns true if the cell should have a *method name* border
            private boolean top(int row)
            {
                if(row==0||row==3||row==6)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }

            private boolean left(int col)
            {
                if(col==0||col==3||col==6)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            private boolean bottom(int row)
            {
                if(row==8)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
            private boolean right(int col)
            {
                if(col==8)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            //returns true if cell should be shaded in gray
            private boolean toBeGray(int row, int col)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> SetA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<Integer> SetB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int[] a = {0,1,2,6,7,8};
                int[] b = {3,4,5};

                for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++ )
                    SetA.add(a[i]);
                for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
                    SetB.add(b[i]);


                if((SetA.contains(row)&&SetA.contains(col))||(SetB.contains(row)&&SetB.contains(col)))
                        return true;                    
                return false;

            }
        };

        //we don't need the table header
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        //set the base GOOEY stuff
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        //we're going to store only single digits, so the size we want is exactly one digit
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(15);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(15);

        //if this table is used to display the result, "closing" the window will just dispose it, and not quit the program
        if(isSolution)
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        else setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        pack();

        //put it somewhere nice
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        //set the size so that its only the size of the 
        setSize(143,176);
        //and we want it at one size only
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
         TableModelListener tableModelListener = new TableModelListener()
           {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
            {
                if(e.getType()==TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
                {
                    System.out.println("YA?");
                }
            }

           };


    }

   @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
    {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
        Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
        table.setValueAt(4, row, column);
        System.out.println("Something happened yay");
        // Do something with the data...
    }


//    
    /**
     * 
     * @return a copy of the board 
     */
   public int[][] getBoard()
   {
       int[][] returnee = new int[9][9];
       for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
                returnee[i] = board[i].clone();
       return returnee;
   }

   /**
    * @return reference to the "real" board
    * @WARNING - By manipulating the array from this method you're manipulating the methods array itself! IF NOT SURE USE THE GetBoard METHOD!
    * 
    */
   public int[][] getRealBoard()
   {
    return board;   
   }

   //------debugging---------------------------
   private void setValue()
   {
      System.out.println(table.getValueAt(3,4));
   }

   public void doStuffs()
   {
       System.out.println(table.isCellEditable(2,2));
   }

   //----------main just for debugging----------
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[][] hi = new int[9][9];
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                hi[i][j]=-1;
        hi[3][3]=0;
        SudokuTablePreRenderer frame = new SudokuTablePreRenderer(hi,false);
        frame.setValue();
        frame.doStuffs();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For some reason you have two 2-dimensional int arrays in your model, data and originalBoard.
- The first array, data, you display information from in the JTable via `getValueAt(...)`
- The second array, originalBoard, you add data to the model via `setValueAt(...)`.
- This disparity means that adding data to the model will have no effect on the data displayed in the JTable which begs the question -- why is your model set up this way?

You state,

> To sum my question, why doesn't my table fire events and can't setValuesAt.

and I'll bet that the table events *do* in fact get fired, but since the data held by the data array never changes, the JTable will never change its display.

If you want new data added to update the display, then the array that gets the data should be the same as the one that displays the data. At least that seems to make the most sense to me.

---

**Edit:**

Regarding:

> Sadly I don't think thats the case. This design is something I did before I found out that arrays are just 'references', and so in reality the two arrays should be the one and same. The other problem is that I put a System.out.print into the setValueAt, and when I called it from inside the model (called get valueAt from outside, and that called setValueAT) it worked perfectly, it set the value, it even fired When I call the method from outside though it doesn't work

You are right, sorry. I retract my answer above.

However, another potential problem: your setValueAt method is not a true override, is never called, and the actual AbstractTableModel setValueAt method which you call is never overridden and will have no effect.

Get rid of the TableModelListener, and change your setValueAt to:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
  originalBoard[row][col] = ((Integer) value).intValue();
  System.out.println("Setting value");
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
  // return true;
}
```

Comment: Sadly I don't think thats the case.
This design is something I did before I found out that arrays are just 'references', and so in reality the two arrays should be the one and same.

The other problem is that I put a System.out.print into the setValueAt, and when I called it from inside the model (called get valueAt from outside, and that called setValueAT) it worked perfectly, it set the value, it even fired
When I call the method from outside though it doesn't work ...

Comment: @user2970002: sorry, you're right. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: Right ...
I got a 'The method setValueAt(int, int, int, int) of type SudokuTableModel must override or implement a supertype method'
error, so I just removed the @Override ...

Comment: @Switha: either make sure to call *your* method, or override the actual method of the Abstract class **with the correct parameters**.

Comment: on last question, does it have to have the fireTableCellUpdated() call? Without it seems to work, but with it when it sets I get a stack overflow ...
I Just checked the jtable tutorial from oracle and it does ... any idea why it could be doing that ?
It just keeps on printing "Setting value", and then stack overflow ... Let me check if I'm not calling it from somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Switha: it only gets the stackoverflow because of recursion, found in your TableModelListener. That's why my answer suggests that you not use *this* TableModelListener.

Comment: Yep it was recursion, it was in the Event Listener ... It says not to thank here, so I'll just leave you with a tick.